# Haskell binary tree

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

I have a homework:

1) define a data structure `TTT` for the tree where each vertex has 0, 1 or 2 children and each tree leaf(vertex with 0 children and itself) contains a list of natural numbers;

2) create a function `mm` which has 2 arguments - function `f(Integer->Integer)` and `TTT` based tree `x`. In result it should give `TTT` based tree which is made from `x` using function `f` for each element in the list(referenced to the 1) definition);

Function `f` can have following representations(`a`, `b` or `c`):

```
a :: Integer -> Integer
a x = x * x

b :: Integer -> Integer
b x = x `mod` 9

c :: Integer -> Integer
c x = x * x * x
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: I am stucked with defining TTT structure :(

Comment: you should read the chapters 1,2 and beginning of 3 of [real world haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org) to get a good understanding and some practice of the language.

Comment: I'll give you a hint for TTT: algebraic data type.

Comment: @werd This is really basic stuff. If you cannot understand your lecture notes then read a tutorial, e.g. [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: FYI the "homework" tag is deprecated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Important Advice

It would really be worth working through [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). It's an excellent tutorial.

Practice! Play! Extend this assignment, by changing the brief. Can you do it for Strings instead of Integers? Can you do a tree with three subtrees? Can you do one where the branches have data too? Can you make a tree that takes any data type? Find out about `Functor`s. Why are they any good? Can you make a tree that represents a calculation, with branches for operations like `+` and leaves for numbers?

The more you play, the more confident you'll be. Be the guy in class that found out about something before it came up. Everyone will ask you for help, then you'll learn even more when you're asked to solve the tricky problems anyone in your group has.

### Question 1: Tree datatype

Here are some hints.

This binary tree has two subtrees or a Boolean leaf:

```
data BTree = Leaf Bool | Branch BTree BTree 
  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

This data structure has three items, including a list of `Bool`s:

```
data Triple = Triple Int String [Bool]
  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

This one has three different possibilities, and because `Expr` appears on the right hand side, it's a bit like a tree.

```
data Expr = Var Char | Lam Char Expr | Let Char Expr Expr
  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Now you need one with three possibilities, where the leaf has a list of Integers, and the other two have one subtree, or two subtrees. Put the ideas in the examples together.

### Question 2: map a function over your tree

We call this apply-a-function-everywhere-you-can "map"ping the function. `map` does it for lists, and `fmap` does it for other things.

Let's define a function that takes a `Bool -> Bool` and maps it over the first example:

```
mapBTree :: (Bool -> Bool) -> BTree -> BTree
mapBTree f (Leaf b) = Leaf (f b)
mapBTree f (Branch b1 b2) = Branch (mapBTree f b1) (mapBTree f b2)
```

and another one that maps over the triple. This time we have to make it work on each of the `Bool`s in the list.

```
mapBoolTriple :: (Bool -> Bool) -> Triple -> Triple
mapBoolTriple f (Triple i xs bs) = Triple i xs (map f bs)
```

Notice I used the standard function `map` which works like this:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

so it applies `f` to each `x` in my list, starting at the front.

### How I'd really do this kind of thing

This isn't how I'd do this for real, though. I'd add

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
```

at the top of my file, which would let me write

```
data BinTree a = ALeaf a | ABranch (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
   deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)
```

and then I could do

```
fmap (*100) (ABranch (ALeaf 12) (ALeaf 34))
```

which would give me

```
ABranch (ALeaf 1200) (ALeaf 3400)
```

but `fmap` is more flexible: I could also do

```
fmap (<20) (ABranch (ALeaf 12) (ALeaf 34))
  -- ABranch (ALeaf True) (ALeaf False)
```

or

```
fmap show (ABranch (ALeaf 12) (ALeaf 34))
 -- ABranch (ALeaf "12") (ALeaf "34")
```

without me writing a single line of the function `fmap`. I think that would give you 10/10 for using additional language features but 0/10 for solving the problem as set, so don't do that, but keep it in mind and use it when you can.

### More advice

Have fun learning Haskell. It can be mind-blowing at times, but it rewards you strongly for learning. You'll be able to write some programs in Haskell a tenth of the length of programs in more conventional languages. Think more! Write less!

Comment: Thanks for advice - will try to put it all together ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this far when it works as expected except that instead of Ingeter list I have one Integer in leaf. My question now is what should I change in this code so that leaf could contain only Integer list? So far I tried modifying the tree definition like this:

```
data TTT a = ALeaf [Integer] | ABranch (TTT a) (TTT a)
```

and modify data:

```
testTree1 = ABranch (ALeaf [1,2,3]) (ALeaf [4,5,6])
```

but in that case Integer list stays un-modified.

Below is the **stable code** with one Integer in leaf which works.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data TTT a = ALeaf a | ABranch (TTT a) (TTT a)
   deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)

-- Function "mm"
mm f t = let
   in fmap (f) t

-- Function "tt_a"
tt_a = mm a testTree1

-- Function "tt_b"
tt_b = mm b testTree1

-- Function "tt_c"
tt_c = mm c testTree1

-- Function "a"
a :: Integer -> Integer
a x = x * x

-- Function "b"
b :: Integer -> Integer
b x = x `mod` 9

-- Function "c"
c :: Integer -> Integer
c x = x * x * x

-- TTT type tree`s for tests
testTree1 = ABranch (ALeaf 1) (ALeaf 2)
testTree2 = ABranch (ALeaf 11) (ALeaf 12)
```

Comment: With `data TTT a = ALeaf [Integer] | ABranch (TTT a) (TTT a)` the derived Functor won't touch the `[Integer]` because it's not got an `a` in it. If you change it to `[a]` fmap will edit it. Don't forget to include the possibility of one child node as an alternative.

Comment: Did you add the one child alternative? Are you sure you're going to get credit for deriving Functor? Why not make sure and do it both ways - write a recursive definition too - maximum opportunity for credit.